# What is difference between WebSocket4Net MessageReceived or DataReceived event?

Tags: websocket4net

What is the difference between [WebSocket4Net](https://websocket4net.codeplex.com/)'s `MessageReceived` or `DataReceived` events?

Answer (score 4):

I identified some differences between MessageReceived or DataReceived event. When server is sending messages in bytes format it will receive in DataReceived event. But if messages is coming in string format it will receive in  MessageReceived event.